# Random mouse movement from position x to position y in Python 3

Tags: python-3.x, random, path, click, mouse

There are some similar threads about it, but I'm looking for something different.
I need a script that will move mouse from one position to another with randomly path and speed in range 0-1,5 sec. That should looks like normal users movement, because noone can move mouse 2x with the same path and speed.

To be more precize:

I need Python to detect the specyfic image in first area, right click on it (but always in a little different pixels of this image), then randomly move mouse to the second image (witch will never change) and left click on it. There will be always 20 the same small pictures on the start. After first "pass" there will be 19 images left, till 0. Would be nice if Python could randomly right click pictures from what left.

I'm attaching a picture to illustrate what I mean:

[image: Random mouse movement]

Is that possible to make in Python 3+ ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can make use of `pyautogui` library and its `moveTo` function.

```
>>> pyautogui.moveTo(100, 100, 2, pyautogui.easeInQuad)     # start slow, end fast
>>> pyautogui.moveTo(100, 100, 2, pyautogui.easeOutQuad)    # start fast, end slow
>>> pyautogui.moveTo(100, 100, 2, pyautogui.easeInOutQuad)  # start and end fast, slow in middle
>>> pyautogui.moveTo(100, 100, 2, pyautogui.easeInBounce)   # bounce at the end
>>> pyautogui.moveTo(100, 100, 2, pyautogui.easeInElastic)  # rubber band at the end
```

Full reference https://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/mouse.html#tween-easing-functions
When it comes to random path I would try generating couple of random points inside specified variance from straight line.